# yum updates failing with primary_db.sqlite: [Errno 27] File too large error

Tags: centos-7, yum

I am running CentOS 7.9 and I added a nvidia repo for yum to update the hpc_sdk. yum was working fine before this, but now I get the error

> Error: Error writing to file /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/base/gen/primary_db.sqlite: [Errno 27] File too large

when I attempt to do anything with yum (e.g. yum info or yum repolist). The /var disk is only 39% full with over 250 GB available so there is not a disk problem. How can I fix this problem?